# Many body BCS theory related question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, superconductivity, mean-field-theory

I am trying to find the mean number of particles in the BCS ground state $|\psi>$, but I am stuck on a step.

$$|\psi> = \Pi_{k}(u_{k} + v_{k}c^{{\dagger}}_{{k}{\uparrow}}c^{\dagger}_{{-k}{\downarrow}})$$

where $u_{k}$, $v_{k}$ are complex numbers.
So to begin, we start with a specific spin state $$<\psi|N_{{p}{\uparrow}}|\psi> =<\psi|c^{{\dagger}}_{{p}{\uparrow}}c_{{p}{\uparrow}}|\psi>$$

This is what I get

$$\Pi_{k} |v_{k}|^{2} (c_{{k}{\uparrow}}c_{{-k}{\downarrow}}c^{{\dagger}}_{{p}{\uparrow}}c_{{p}{\uparrow}}c^{{\dagger}}_{{k}{\uparrow}}c^{\dagger}_{{-k}{\downarrow}})$$

I don't know how to simplify this or if I am even on right track. Any hints?

Comment: put the orders in normal order using the anti-commutation rule for fermion operators.  Search Wick's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a calculation based on a general Bogoluibov transformation 
$$
a_i= u_{i\beta}b_\beta +v^*_{i\beta}b^\dagger_\beta\\
a^\dagger_i= v_{i\alpha} b_\alpha +u^*_{i\alpha}b^\dagger_\alpha.
$$
With $\vert 0 \rangle_b$ being the vacuum state for the $b_\alpha$'s  we have
$$
N=\sum_i { _b\langle{0}\vert{ a^\dagger_i a_i}\vert{0}\rangle _b} \\
={\sum_{i,\alpha,\beta}  { _b\langle{0}\vert{( v_{i\alpha} b_\alpha +u^*_{i\alpha}b^\dagger_\alpha)(u_{i\beta}b_\beta +v^*_{i\beta}b^\dagger_\beta)}\vert{0}\rangle_b}}\\
  =  \sum_{i,\alpha,\beta} (v_{i\alpha} v^*_{i\beta})  {_b\langle{0}\vert{ b_\alpha b^\dagger_\beta }\vert{0}\rangle_b}\\
  =\sum_{\alpha,\beta} v_{i\alpha} v^*_{i\beta}  \delta_{\alpha\beta}\\
  = \sum_\alpha |v_\alpha|^2.
$$
We can  also write 
$$
N= \frac 12 \sum_{\alpha=1}^N\left((|v_\alpha|^2-|u_\beta|^2) + (|u_\alpha|^2+|v_\alpha|^2)\right)\\
=\frac 12 \sum_{\alpha=1}^N\left((|v_\alpha|^2-|u_\beta|^2) + 1\right),
$$
which looks like the contribution of  the Dirac sea   negative-energy Bogoliubov-de Gennes equation eigenstates $(v^*_\alpha, u^*_\alpha)$, but corrected by an infinite normal-ordering counterterm (the sum of all the ``+1''s).

As an aside, note I'm not sure that your BCS ground state is  normalized. I like to write 
$$
\vert{0}\rangle _b ={\mathcal N}  \exp\left\{\frac 12 a^\dagger_i a^\dagger_jS_{ij}\right\} \vert{0}\rangle_a
$$
where 
$$
S_{ij}=   v^*_{i\alpha}(u^*)^{-1}_{\alpha j}
$$
is skew symmetric 
and 
$$
{\mathcal N}= {\rm det}^{-1/4}(I+S^\dagger S)
$$
is derived by  using the fermionic version of MacMahon's master theorem. This way makes clear that the BCS ground state is  a coherent state superposition  of Cooper pairs with pair "wavefunction" $S_{ij}$.

Note added: Yes your state is normalized. It's just not the way I like to write it.

Comment: May I ask how is the last equation about the normalization constant derived (in detail)? or if it has been shown at any reference? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a rather lengthy and indiect proof using canonical forms. The bose version  is in  Schwinger's essay *On Angular Momentum* which is reprinted in Biedenharn and  Van Dam,
 *Quantum Theory of Angular Momentum*, Academic Press, 1965. The only derivation I have seen in print of the fermionic version  is in Pressley and Segal's book *Loop Groups* which is in my inaccessible office.

Comment: Can you tell me which section? Thanks!

Comment: another related question is that, let's say, by tuning the parameter in the BdG Hamiltonian, we obtain a new pairing ground state proportional to $\Omega_1 = \exp(\frac{1}{2}\tilde{S}_{i,j}c^\dagger_i c_j)|0\rangle$ (the normalization factor can be calculated just use the formula you give above), then what would be the overlap between $|\Omega_1\rangle$ and $|\Omega_0 \rangle = \exp(\frac{1}{2}S_{i,j}c^\dagger_i c_j)|0\rangle$ (which is proportional to the ground state of initial Hamiltonian)?
Is there also a simple formula for it?
Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that the overlap between different pairing states has been studied before. There is a so-called Onishi formula, but with a "sign problem", which is solved in this beautiful paper: https://journals.aps.org/prc/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevC.50.2874

Comment: @Chuan Chen. Cool!  The section in  the Loop Groups book is Proposition 12.2.3 on page 235. Some other material can be found in the note on BCS at http://people.physics.illinois.edu/stone/

Comment: Many thanks! I will read them carefully :)